# Force Glue Crawler to use pre-defined Glue Table

Tags: aws-glue

How would one go about configuring a Glue crawler to not create its own schema, but use the pre-defined (manually entered) schema/cols in a Glue table?  Every time I try it, the crawler just creates a new table.  The reason I need to do this is because the CSV file has no header record so I do not want the crawler to guess at the cols and datatype of each.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using custom [classifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html#custom-classifier-csv). Please refer to the attached screenshot which says no headings available where you can provide column names.[image]

Attach this classifier to your crawler and run it.